# BATで0埋めの連番を出力したい

Tags: batch-file

以下の様に書いても、008の次に001が表示され、009以降の表示が出来ないのですが
どの様にすれば良いのでしょうか

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET NUM=1
:Loop
IF !NUM! LEQ 99 ( IF !NUM! LEQ 9 (SET NUM=00!NUM!) else (SET NUM=0!NUM!) ) else (SET NUM=!NUM!)
ECHO !NUM!
SET /A NUM+=1
GOTO :Loop
EndLocal
EXIT /B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

テクニックの問題として、`1`ではなく`100`など大きな数値で計算を行い、下２桁を参照することで簡単に`0`補完できます。

```
@ECHO OFF
SET NUM=100
:Loop
SET /A NUM+=1
echo %NUM:~-2%
IF NOT "%NUM:~-2%"=="00" GOTO Loop
EXIT /B
```

---

ちなみに`008`の次が`1`となる原因ですが、たぶん数値が`0`から始まっているため８進数と解釈されたためと思われます。８進数で有効な数字は`0`～`7`なので`8`や`9`は非数値として無視され`00`として扱われています。
数値保存用の変数と文字列用の変数を分けるべきです。

---

なお、`GOTO`を用いたループについての質問を受けたため、`GOTO`を用いたループで回答しました。その回答に対して`FOR /F`を用いた問題が解決できないとコメントされても困ります。`FOR /F`を用いた問題を解決したいのであれば、`FOR /F`を用いた問題について質問するべきです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

回答に気付かず質問の編集を行ってしまい申し訳ありません。
先ほど0揃えの方は治ったのですが、うまくループしてくれない方についてのご教授をお願いしてもよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 私の回答であれば、`01`～`99`、`00`のループが実現できています。何が問題となっているのでしょうか？

Comment: `for /f`を用いて`1～99`、`01～99`、`001～999`など複数の種類の出力が必要でしたが
教えていただいたやり方ですと処理の変更が(面倒な方法しか)分からなかったので避けたかったのです

また、以下のやり方で009以降の出力が問題なく行えました
`IF !NUM! LEQ 99 ( IF !NUM! LEQ 9 (SET NUM2=00!NUM!) else (SET NUM2=0!NUM!) ) else (SET NUM2=!NUM!)`
わがままに付き合わせてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。

Comment: @水瀬敦美 質問文に書かれていない話題については、質問者さんにしかわからず、誰も答えようがないことをご理解ください。必要であれば質問を行うことをおすすめします。

Comment: 確かに質問文に書かれていないことに関しては質問者にしか分かり得ない事ですが、当方の質問した「9以降の出力」についてはそれらの情報が不要だと判断出来ましたので省かせて頂きました。
また、先ほど一度書き込みましたが、以下の記述で出力が行えた為、この質問は解決致しました。
`IF !NUM! LEQ 99 ( IF !NUM! LEQ 9 (SET NUM2=00!NUM!) else (SET NUM2=0!NUM!) ) else (SET NUM2=!NUM!)`
拙い文章故色々とお手数をお掛けしてしまい申し訳ありませんでした。